# IOS 17 Safari not accepting PWA icon on 'Add to Home Screen'

Tags: html, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, mobile-safari

IOS 17 Safari not accepting PWA icon on 'Add to Home Screen'. It just generates a generic default gray background with a single letter for the icon.

I have tried various approaches to get it to accept the icon but to no avail so far. Here is the html and manifest that I believe should be working but isn't:

```
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/media/logos/logo-16.png">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="PWT App">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/media/logos/logo-180.png">

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">

    <link rel="manifest" href="/app.webmanifest">

</head>
```

The manifest icons is:

```
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "/assets/media/logos/logo-256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/assets/media/logos/logo-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "any"
        },
        {
            "src": "/assets/media/logos/logo-512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        }
    ]
```

Any ideas? Chrome on Mac is detecting and using the icon when saving the web application. But safari 17 on iPhone will not. FYI: I am getting a PWA green check from Chrome's Lighthouse when auditing the site for PWA compliance. And I am running all this under an https nodejs local server, which does mean I am accessing the web app resources through a local router's IP address -- not sure if that would make a difference, but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: there are new argument arising the eu users wont be able to use it any more in the context of pwa.